# My Bash script works improperly

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am making a bash script that displays a grade based on what the user enters. However, it is returning the wrong grade and I can't figure out why. I posted the code below. I am new to bash scripting as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter assignment mark (0 to 40): "
read assignment
echo "Enter Test1 mark (0 to 15): "
read test1
echo "Enter Test2 mark (1 to 15): "
read test2
echo "Enter Final Exam mark (1 to 30): "
read final

(( sum = ( $assignment / 40 * 40 ) + (  $test1 / 15 *15 ) + ( $test2 / 15 * 15 ) + ( $final / 30 * 30 ) ))

if [ $sum -ge "90" ] && [ $sum -le "100" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is an A+."
elif [ $sum -ge "85" ] && [ $sum -le "89" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a A."
elif [ $sum -ge "80" ] && [ $sum -le "84" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a A-."
elif [ $sum -ge "77" ] && [ $sum -le "79" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a B+."
elif [ $sum -ge "73" ] && [ $sum -le "76" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a B."
elif [ $sum -ge "70" ] && [ $sum -le "72" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a B-."
elif [ $sum -ge "67" ] && [ $sum -le "69" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a C+."
elif [ $sum -ge "63" ] && [ $sum -le "66" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a C."
elif [ $sum -ge "60" ] && [ $sum -le "62" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a C-."
elif [ $sum -ge "57" ] && [ $sum -le "59" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is a D+."
elif [ $sum -ge "53" ] && [ $sum -le "56" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is an D."
elif [ $sum -ge "50" ] && [ $sum -le "52" ]
then
echo "Your final grade is an D-."
elif [ $sum -le "49" ] 
then
echo "Your final grade is an F. Sorry!"
fi
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "works improperly" means? What do you see? What do you expect?

Comment: WHat does the sum line suppose to calculate?     Why /40*40?

Comment: why not just summing up the numbers instead of multiplying and diving by the same number? :D

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add what it does. It takes the grades the user enters and displays a mark out of 100. The assignment mark is out of 40 and worth 40% of the grade, the test1 and test2 marks are each out of 15 and each worth 15% of the grade, and the final exam mark is out of 30 and is worth 30% of the grade (40+15+15+30=100). The final mark is out of 100, which is why I multiply the marks. I can put in 40, 14, 14, 30 and the script displays "you got a b+" when it should be an A/A+. So the math seems to be wrong but I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Richard - You do realize that if `$assignment < 40`, then `$assignment / 40` will always be `0`, right? The shell does integer math, not floating point math (at least not without additional work...)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand this line:

```
(( sum = ( $assignment / 40 * 40 ) + (  $test1 / 15 *15 ) + ( $test2 / 15 * 15 ) + ( $final / 30 * 30 ) ))
```

Dividing and multiplying by the same number seems to be useless. Why not changing it to

```
(( sum =  $assignment + $test1 + $test2 + $final ))
```

EDIT: This code works. Enjoy ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter assignment mark (0 to 40): "
read assignment
echo "Enter Test1 mark (0 to 15): "
read test1
echo "Enter Test2 mark (1 to 15): "
read test2
echo "Enter Final Exam mark (1 to 30): "
read final

sum=$(( assignment  +  test1  +  test2 + final  ))

if [[ $sum -ge 90 ]] && [[ $sum -le 100 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is an A+.
elif [[ $sum -ge 85 ]] && [[ $sum -le 89 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a A.
elif [[ $sum -ge 80 ]] && [[ $sum -le 84 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a A-.
elif [[ $sum -ge 77 ]] && [[ $sum -le 79 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a B+.
elif [[ $sum -ge 73 ]] && [[ $sum -le 76 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a B.
elif [[ $sum -ge 70 ]] && [[ $sum -le 72 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a B-.
elif [[ $sum -ge 67 ]] && [[ $sum -le 69 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a C+.
elif [[ $sum -ge 63 ]] && [[ $sum -le 66 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a C.
elif [[ $sum -ge 60 ]] && [[ $sum -le 62 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a C-.
elif [[ $sum -ge 57 ]] && [[ $sum -le 59 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is a D+.
elif [[ $sum -ge 53 ]] && [[ $sum -le 56 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is an D.
elif [[ $sum -ge 50 ]] && [[ $sum -le 52 ]]
then
echo Your final grade is an D-.
elif [[ $sum -le 49 ]] 
then
echo Your final grade is an F. Sorry!
fi
```

Comment: Yes I guess that works, I had the multiplication in though because the assignment mark is worth 40%, test1 mark worth 15%, test2 mark worth 15%, and final exam mark worth 30% of the total mark, but I guess it was unnecessary. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Acutally this doesn't work because it does not take into consideration the weight of each mark.

Comment: As far as I can understand you define the weight by the number of points (40,15,15,30) so I don't see the issue.

Comment: You do realize that if `$assignment < 40`, then `$assignment / 40` will always be `0`, right? The shell does integer math, not floating point math (at least not without additional work...)...

Comment: I'm not dividing anything in my code, and again, [taking in account @Richard requirements], this script works for me.

Comment: @ophintor Sorry... should have directed that comment at the OP. You're right - your updated version doesn't divide... But I think the expectation of floating point math is the OPs core problem with his original code.

Comment: No problem. It seems clear that dividing is not necessary as the scripts is asking for an amount of points off 100 that is exactly the same as its weight.

Comment: Damn I feel like an idiot, sorry about doubting this answer. It is correct. Thanks all!!!